# Trying to enable .htacccess in apache2 but my default.conf is relatively empty

Tags: 14.04, apache2, .htaccess

I've been trying to enable .htaccess for all of my domains in apache2 which is running on ubuntu  14.04, but my default configuration file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` appears rather barren in comparison to what guides say it should look like.

This is my `000-default.conf` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port t$
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin ethenders@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

But [guides suggest](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnablingUseOfApacheHtaccessFiles) it should look like, or have this section:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    # Uncomment this directive is you want to see apache2's
    # default start page (in /apache2-default) when you go to /
    #RedirectMatch ^/$ /apache2-default/
</Directory>
```

I've added that suggested code to my `000-default.conf` file, and restarted apache2, but nothing happens. There is no error message, it just restarts and reloads normally.

Nothing changes, .htaccess files are still ignored. Any help I could get would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I was trying to use `/var/www/` in my `000-default.conf` file which actually utilizes `/var/www/html`, and I essentially replicated that error to each subdomain I tried this on (would just tell it to use `/var/www/` not the actual subdomain's folder).